# How do I pass data between tvml views?

Tags: json, tvos

I need to pass data between views in my client-server app. For simple string value, I can put them as attributes on the target element and read the value when the `select` event is triggered on it. From there, I can pass this string value onto the next document pretty easily.

But the problem comes with much more complex data that's in JSON format. I tried doing `JSON.stringify(myData)` and putting this value in an attribute. But the compiler doesn't like the `{` in this attribute value.

I could probably try escaping all the different characters that the compiler has problems with. But I don't think that's a good idea.

Is there any way of implementing `jQuery`'s `.data()` functionality in `TVML` and `TVJS` ? Or is there any other way that makes sending data between views a possibility ?

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing your architecture. In my app I have a button which is supposed to play all videos in a category. This button just contains the index of the category as an attribute. I pass the value of this attribute to a function in the controller for that view which returns the correct category object.

Comment: I have setup a data service. I use this service to save and retrieve data now. When creating a view, I generate a guid and save corresponding data with this guid to Data service. And pass the guid to the Presenter as an attribute, so that it retrieves the data from the service and passes it to the view that is being invoked. Solves my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your data as URL parameters. Then in the new view, get them using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: And I see in the comment above you came to a similar conclusion.

You could keep your data in a semi-global associative array. Store the key in an attribute on the element and use that to get your data structure.

Ex:

```
var globalData;

function onSelect(e){
  var id=e.target.getAttribute("id");
  var specificData=globalData[id];
}
```